# Does conversion of an integer to string using str() method in python takes extra space?

Tags: python-3.x, function

Working on a question that says to check if the integer is a palindrome without using extra space, I converted it to string and solved it in o(1) and the answer got accepted, but I'm not sure if it is the right way to do it

```
#A is an int
A=str(A)
```

Comment: It's not O(1)... It's O(N) where N is the number of digits in the value, and yes, a string consumes more space than an integer

Comment: @cricket_007: and that's the minimum, O(1) is impossible.

Comment: @ManmeetSethi: Yes it uses some extra space, but I don't think it's possible to do it without using _any_ extra space.

Answer (score 0):

depends on how big the number is.

In general int are smaller than string.

python use class to represent `int` and `str`
which have some overhead that take some space

i.e:

```
>>> import sys

>>> n = 10
>>> sys.getsizeof(10)
28
>>> s = str(n)
>>> sys.getsizeof(s)
51
```